# What will happen when the endorsing peer is down?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In my example, there are 3 participants orgs - Org1, Org2 and Org3

Endorsement policy states - Endorsement is required from all 3 orgs. 
What if org3 is down due to unavoidable circumstances and assuming it will take a day for them to be booted back again. In the meantime, all the transactions won't go through because of endorsement policies.

Can we tackle this kind of scenario ? (say) modifying the endorsement policy or some kind of threshold mechanism ?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the endorsement policy in this case would not be possible by Fabric---for many valid reasons, including security and contractual concerns. You can either begin with a less stringent endorsement policy, or simply, have 2 or more peers per org and the set the end. policy to ANY peer from EACH org. That way, if one peer of an org is down, the other peer can keep the operation going.